# I made changes in my CSS file but I can't see the changes in a browser

Tags: html, css

I made some changes to my CSS file. I can see the new version on any browser but firefox. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be **caused by cache**. Possible solutions to your problem are available here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1147504; the accepted answer at the website is:

> One way to check whether this is a problem with stored data in Firefox
>   is to test in a new private window. When you launch the first private
>   window in a regular browsing session, it has an empty cache and empty
>   cookie jar and should give you a clean retrieval of the current site.
>   If you still get old data, the problem is external to Firefox, for
>   example, a proxy server or ISP cache.
>
> Close all the private windows if you want to test again, since they
>   share a temporary cache and cookie jar until the last one is closed.

You can also try to reload the page as mentioned below (this bypasses the current cache) (source: https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/967500):

> Reload web page(s) and bypass the cache to refresh possibly outdated
>   or corrupted files.
>
> Hold down the Shift key and left-click the Reload button
>   Press "Ctrl + F5" or press "Ctrl + Shift + R" (Windows,Linux)
>   Press "Command + Shift + R" (Mac)